# wget mirror with "pretty urls" structure

Tags: wget, github-pages

I'm using the following command to grab a site `wget --mirror --page-requisites --convert-links --adjust-extension --span-hosts --restrict-file-names=windows --no-parent https://example.com`

I want to host the static site on GitHub pages, so for URLs like `/content/foo` I'd like to get `/content/foo/index.html`. Currently I get `/content/foo.html`.

My question is how to get that `index.html` added, as GitHub pages will know how to server `/content/foo/` given the `index.html` is present.

Comment: In GitHub pages you can also access as `https://<githubusername>.github.io/content/foo/` So my problem is how to have that `/content/foo/index.html` created in the first place

Comment: My current hack for this - given that my Drupal installation is meant to accessible only for content editors - is to set the "path alias" to be `/content/foo/index.html`. Then wget obviously gets it right. Ugly, but it works. Still would be interested to hear if there's a way to solve it in a cleaner way.